# OSMConvert - where to obtain package

Tags: openstreetmap, osmconvert

I am trying to download the OSMConvert Linux package but it seems to have vanished. Does anyone have a reliable download link for either the Linux or MacOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, found the correct install for **Ubuntu**.

For others reference:-

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install osmctools
```

The osmctools package includes the useful osmconvert to enable you to convert easily between various formats eg osm to pbf for example.

Might be of use to others who need software to do such translations. Although if you download FME Deskload its free trial will give you access to a very wide range of such translations.